# override methods of generic base type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, interface

My current structure looks like this:

```
public class CustomerRepository
{
    // ..

    public virtual Customer LoadCustomer()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class OracleCustomerRepository : CustomerRepository
{
    private OracleConnection oracleConnection;

    public OracleCustomerRepository()
    : base(){
        if(this.EnsureIsConnected()){
             // ...
        }
    }

    private bool EnsureIsConnected(){
        // ..
    }

    public override Customer LoadCustomer(){
        // ..
    }
}
```

That works well, except for the fact that - for every `OracleRepository` - I have to write the methods `EnsureIsConnected` again, I have to declare the filed `OracleConnection` again etc.

I'd like to abstract that. My first idea was to use an `Interface` but that doesn't solve the problem of the duplicate code. My second idea was to use the base class `CustomerRepository` as a generic type for another new base class `OracleRepository<T>`, which then defines the common routines.

The problem is: As far as I know there's no way to `override` the `virtual` methods of the generic type, e.g `CustomerRepository`.

That's how I thought it would work.

```
public class OracleRepository<T> where T : class{

    public OracleRepository(){
        this.EnsureIsConnected());
    }

    protected OracleConnection oracleConnection;

    protected EnsureIsConnected(){
        // ...
    }
}

public class OracleCustomerRepository : OracleRepository<CustomerRepository>{

    // ..

    // this is not possible, defined in CustomerRepository
    public override Customer LostCustomer(){

    }
}
```

Note: `CustomerRepository` is not the only repository I have. That's mainly the reason why I'm trying to find a better solution.

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: " As far as I know there's no way to override the virtual methods of the generic type" - can you provide an example of what you believe is not possible?

Comment: May be it is written not clear enough, but in any case if you have virtual method in base class you can override it. Generic virtual methods can be overridden in the same way as any other virtual methods

Comment: @MichaelKokorin The virtual methods are defined in the generic type, not the base class. I'll update the post with an example.

Comment: "I want to abstract the OracleConnection stuff." that sounds almost like you could use a strategy pattern here. Do you intend for the `CustomerRepository` to use different connection types for different DB types?

Comment: @MongZhu Every different DB type would be a new implementation of ```CustomerRepository```.

Comment: "Every different DB type would be a new implementation of CustomerRepository" why exactly? in a strategy pattern you would simply exchange the connection type and the whole repository can still work as intended. (at least in theory ;) )

Comment: It still does, the same methods are still available. but, for example, an oracle DB has a different API than MS-SQL or even a normal file. There's no way to abstract that in a good way (at least for me)

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is that your abstraction seems a bit leaking.
What I usually do is to create interface for interacting with database engine, with methods like:

```
public interface IPersistence
{
    void ExecuteOperation(string prodecureName, Dictionary<string, object> parameters);
    T ExecuteSingle(string procedureName, Dictionary<string, object> parameters, Func<IDataReader, T> rowReader);
    List<T> ExecuteMultirow(string procedureName, Dictionary<string, object> parameters, 
Func<IDataReader, T> rowReader);
}
```

And then in repository I put it as dependency and from IoC container decide which implementation to use.
So in your code you'd have:

```
public class CustomerRepository
{
    private readonly IPersistence persistence;

    public CustomerRepository(IPersistence persistence)
    {
        this.persistence = persistence;
    }

    public virtual Customer LoadCustomer()
    {
        // preparation code
        return this.persistence.ExecuteSingle("some procedure", parameters, r => new Customer((int)r["Id"], (string)r["DisplayName"]));
    }
}
```

Comment: The internal database routines are already defined, so that's not the problem. I want to put the common connection stuff (e.g checking if a connection is available) in a base class because it's always the same. But yet I also want to be able to override the methods I defined in the other repository class.

Comment: I'm not sure if checking connection availability should be responsibility of the repository class. I'd do it at the place where I execute queries.

Comment: Maybe I wrote it a bit unclear: I need to validate the connection to the database itself on the startup, every place where a query will be executed does checks as well. But I need an initial check at the startup to get the instance itself.

Comment: But if you move this check to initialization of the IPersistence implementation, it will be checked on initialization of CustomerRepository. I don't get why you need this initial check, but maybe I just don't know entire architecture you're dealing with.

Comment: The interface idea was my first try, but I'd still have to implement it in my class - which is the same implementation for every repository. That's the thing I don't want to write for every repository again. Otherwise your approach would work, that's what I had in mind at first.

Comment: Look at my CustomerRepository implementation. Repository doesn't implement IPersistence. It just gets it's instance and uses it's methods. You'd configure your IoC to pass there OraclePersistence and it will be implemented only once.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do this? Or is this not what you are looking for?

```
public abstract class CustomerRepository<T>
{
    protected OracleConnection oracleConnection;

    protected CustomerRepository() : base(){
        if(EnsureIsConnected()){
            // ...
        }
    }

    protected bool EnsureIsConnected()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public abstract T Load();
}

public class OracleCustomerRepository : CustomerRepository<Customer>
{
    public override Customer Load(){
        return new Customer();
    }
}
```

Comment: That sort of what I already have, I want to abstract the OracleConnection stuff. I've updated my post.

Comment: that could live in the abstract base class, couldn't it?

Comment: That works but that's not the only repository I have. I don't really want to create such a base class for every repository, that just shifts the problem a layer down.

Comment: Could you have an abstract generic base class maybe with CRUD operations then? With anything more specific living in the concrete repositories?